# Can two blocks have the same block.timestamp

Tags: solidity

For Ethereum, and BSC? There are some proposals but how are they impletemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. One of the rules for a new block is that its timestamp is greater than the previous block's.

This applies to all blocks in the canonical chain. I believe uncle blocks may have the same timestamp, since their contents are not part of the canonical chain.

Comment: I read this from someone else too, could you provide a source on this? I was browsing earlier today and saw someone's geth allowing same timestamps in different blocks https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/21184#:~:text=When%20mining%20a%20new%20block%20in%20a%20clique%20network%20it,row%20that%20share%20a%20timestamp.

Comment: The link you provided discusses this. It is a part of the ethash consensus rules, but other consensus engines like clique don't necessarily have the same constraints.